# Facebook Like Button Event Subscribe

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, callback, facebook-like

I'm trying to track the FB likes/unlikes of our site, I've got as far as it all working, people can like or dislike and the tracking works.

Here's my problem when a user isn't logged in the login overlay opens and a user can login, fine, the problem is when a user does need to login the callback for edge.create doesn't get fired and therefore I have no idea whether a user has clicked like or not, resulting in not being able to track the click in GA.

So my question is, is there a event listener for login and click?

my code for reference - Code works fine just need the callback to fire after login:

```
// Register Like
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
    GASocialTracker('like', 'Social Overlay');
    // Close Window.
    hideOverlay('liked');
});

// Register Unlike
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove', function(href, widget) {
    GASocialTracker('unlike', 'Social Overlay');
    // Close Window.
    hideOverlay('unliked');
});
```

If more details are required please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: There are several events concerning login/login status of the user; but I don’t think you can get them to work in connection with the like button and its events. You will be able to know that the user logged in, but not that that happen because they clicked on a like button resp. if they actually liked the page after that. Perhaps you should rather file a bug report, and ask them to make `edge.create` work in this scenario as well.

Comment: Can you try this approach: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23907386/561485

Comment: Thanks for both comments unfortunately they don't work. I'm wondering if creating an app would work.